# MongoDB relacionar un Schema Usuario con otro Schema Mensajes (1:n)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Quisiera hacer una **relacion 1:n** con mis `Schemas` **Usuarios** y **Mensajes**.

**user.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
    var db = require('../libs/db-connection')();
    var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;


    var User = new Schema({
        nombre_real:String,
        apellidos:String,
        pais:String,
        ciudad:String,
        email:{type:String,unique:true},
        nombre_usuario:{type:String, unique:true},
        password:String,
        url_img_perfil:String
    });

    return db.model('usuarios',User);
}
```

**message.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
    var db = require('../libs/db-connection')();
    var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;


    var Message = new Schema({
        titulo:String,
        contenido:String,
        createAt:Date.now()
    });

    return db.model('mensajes',Message);
}
```

Yo había pensado en añadir un campo `creador` en `message.js` y ahí indicar el `_id` del usuario. Algo así:

```
module.exports = function () {
    var db = require('../libs/db-connection')();
    var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;


    var Message = new Schema({
        titulo:String,
        contenido:String,
        createAt:Date.now(),
        //campo añadido para hacer la referencia
        creador:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'usuarios'},
    }); 

    return db.model('mensajes',Message);
}
```

Comment: Lo que pretendes es correcto. ¿Lo has probado? Así como lo tienes está planteada una relación ***1:n***, que es lo mismo que decir 1 usuario puede emitir *n* mensajes.

Comment: Pues lo estoy probando pero me esta dando un error en los routing y estoy viendo que, porque es extraño, es lo que hago siempre y nunca me dio este error . `TypeError: Message.find(...).then(...).cath is not a function`

Comment: Revisa la tipografía. tienes `cath`, te falta una letra `c`, debe ser `catch`